# MySQL -> Select second lowest value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm currently using `min()` to find the lowest value within MYSQL database.

How could i find the second lowest value?

```
'select Date, Horse, ParentID, min(odds2) 
from horsesrp 
where odds2 < 3.1 and odds2 > 1.9 
and Date = "'.$id.'" 
AND Track IN ("Kempton (AW)","Wolverhampton (AW)") 
group by ParentID order by ParentID'
```

please note i still need to order by ParentID as i want to get the second lowest odds2 per parentid

so my database look like:

```
Racetime Odds

13:05     2
13:05     2.4
13:05     3
13:05     5
13:30     3
13:30     5
13:30     9
13:30     13.5
14:00     1.14
14:00     1.19
14:00     2
14:00     4
```

i want to find the second lowest value for each time but it must be between 1 and 2.9

```
Racetime Odds

13:05     2.4
14:00     1.19
```

so the output for the above would be

Thanks

Emma

Comment: order by `odds2 desc` and add a `LIMIT 1,1` clause to the query

Comment: i still need to order by parentid

Comment: you should specify more details. for instance, why do you want to order the results by parentID? Do you need to find second lowest value by each parentID?

Comment: Correct. so for each parent id i want to find to second lowest odds2

Comment: @emmaperkins you can order by two columns, so `ORDER BY ParentID, odds2 desc LIMIT 1,1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the second lowest value in several ways.  If you are starting with this query:

```
select Date, Horse, ParentID, min(odds2) 
from horsesrp 
where odds2 < 3.1 and odds2 > 1.9 and Date = "'.$id.'" AND
      Track IN ("Kempton (AW)","Wolverhampton (AW)") 
group by ParentID
order by ParentID;
```

Then the easiest way is to use the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
select Date, Horse, ParentID, min(odds2),
       substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(odds2) order by odds2, ',', 2), ',', -1) as second_odds
from horsesrp 
where odds2 < 3.1 and odds2 > 1.9 and Date = "'.$id.'" AND
      Track IN ('Kempton (AW)', 'Wolverhampton (AW)') 
group by ParentID
order by ParentID;
```

I am a bit befuddled, though, on what this has to do with your sample data.  There is no `racetime` in the query.

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1, 1
```

Answer (score 3):

This is from example of another question,

```
Product_id reg_price  sale_price

244         50          40

244         45          40 

244         45           0   

244         40           0
```

To find the second lowest sale_price,

```
SELECT
    MIN(NULLIF(sale_price, 0))
FROM `table`
WHERE product_id = 244;
```

**EDIT 1**

so in your case,

```
SELECT
MIN(NULLIF(odds2,0))
FROM horserp
order by ParentID asc;
```

this should order by ParentID as well...

**EDIT 2 - Second query**

```
Select TOP 1 odds2 as '2nd lowest'
from (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 odds2 from horserp ORDER BY odds2 ASC)
a ORDER BY odds2 DESC
```

**EDIT 3 - Further nesting of second query**

```
select *
from (Select TOP 1 odds2 as '2nd lowest'
from (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 odds2 from horserp ORDER BY odds2 ASC) a ORDER BY odds2 DESC)
order by ParentID desc;
```

Comment: does this not just find the 2nd if min is 0?

Comment: correct but would this quesry not select the 2nd min if the first value = something

Comment: but its not null ... i have a value in there and want to just get the second lowest not matter what the value of the first is

Comment: yah, i got it finally so i have editted my answer accordingly.. i hope the second edit helps..

Comment: but i need to order by ParentID - i added extra inot my post to show this

Comment: okay, so i have made a third edit, with more nesting.. hope the third edit helps you.. sorry for the delay..

Answer (score 1):

**Query**

```
Select TOP 1 Salary as '2nd Lowest Salary'
from (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 Salary from Employee ORDER BY Salary ASC)
a ORDER BY Salary DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    SELECT ParentID, Horse, Date, min(odds2) FROM
    (
            select DISTINCT HP.ParentID, HP.Horse, HP.Date, HP.odds2, SUB.min_odd from
            horsesrp HP INNER JOIN 
            (
              SELECT parentID,Date,Horse,min(odds2) min_odd FROM horsesrp GROUP BY parentID,parentID,Date,Horse
            ) SUB ON HP.ParentID = SUB.ParentID AND HP.Date = SUB.Date AND HP.Horse = SUB.Horse WHERE HP.odds2 < 3.1 and HP.odds2 > 1.9 
and HP.Date = "'.$id.'" 
AND HP.Track IN ("Kempton (AW)","Wolverhampton (AW)") AND HP.odds2>SUB.min_odd 
    ) SUB_END
    GROUP BY ParentID, Horse, Date
    ORDER BY ParentID
```

the problem here is that since you're getting the second lowest, you will not see the min values if you have only 1 row for a specific parentID.

The code may have errors, please let me know.

Comment: i need to order by parentid